# Angular custom control and validation using template forms

Tags: javascript, angular, validation, angular2-directives

I've created a custom date picker:

```
template:
`
    <div style="float: left; margin-right: 2px">
        <label for="dayPicker">Day</label>
        <select [(ngModel)]="day" name="dayPicker" class="form-control" id="dayPicker" style="width:83px;" required>
            <option *ngFor="let day of days" [value]="day">{{day}}</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div style="float: left; margin-right: 2px">
        <label for="monthPicker" >Month</label>
        <select [(ngModel)]="month" name="monthPicker" class="form-control" id="monthPicker" style="width:83px;" required>
            <option *ngFor="let x of months" [value]="x.MonthId">{{x.MonthName}}</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div style="float: left;">
        <label for="yearPicker">Year</label>
        <select [(ngModel)]="year" name="yearPicker" class="form-control"  id="yearPicker" style="width:92px;" required>
            <option *ngFor="let year of years" [value]="year">{{year}}</option>
        </select>      
    </div>  
`
```

and I use it like this:

```
        <date-picker [(inputDate)]="travel.FromDate" name="FromDate" id="FromDate" [yearBegin]="yearListBegin" [yearEnd]="yearListEnd" 
            (dateChange)="onFromDateChange($event, travel.IndependentTravelId)" datePickerRequired required>                    
        </date-picker>
```

I have wrote a custom Directive for this because I want to validate the control.

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[datePickerRequired]',
    providers: [
        { provide: NG_VALIDATORS, useExisting: forwardRef(() => DatePickerValidator), multi: true }
    ]
})

export class DatePickerValidator implements Validator  {

    validator: Function;

    constructor() { 
        this.validator = this.datePickerValidator();
    }

    validate(c: FormControl) {
        return this.validator(c);
    }

    datePickerValidator(): ValidatorFn {
        return (c: FormControl) => {
            const date = Date.parse(c.value);
            if(isNaN(date)) {
                return {
                    valid: false
                }
            } else {
                return null;
            }            
        }
    }
}
```

The date picker control itself works how I want it to. The problem is that I cannot get the control to validate properly. The datePickerValidator() validator function does not execute.

As per various examples, I tried putting the #FromDate="ngModel" into the  tag but that causes this JavaScript error:

```
There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "ngModel"
```

The examples on the net I found are not quite like mine, as in a custom control consisting of multiple controls. How do I set the code up so my date picker control validates?

Comment: Did you import `FormsModule` in your module?

Comment: Yes, I have added it.